# How can I make clicking on printed text in the VS Code Debug Panel take me to the Dart/Flutter code which printed it?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I develop my Flutter app with Vscode.
I'd like to know how or whether it's possible to make the print output in the debug console clickable, because I always forget to remove the `print()` lines from my code, and It takes me forever to locate them later.

Image for reference:

[image]

This is a print statement, which I'd like to be able to press in order to take me to the file that outputs this.

Following @starball's advice, this is the result I'm getting:
[image]

The print isn't clickable.

Comment: did you actually print `Platform.script.path`? Or just hardcode `/main.dart`? Because unless your main.dart is located at the root of your filesystem, that's not going to work. You need to give the actual path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to make it easier to get back to things and delete them after the print statement is no longer needed, I think what you can do is print the value of `Platform.script.path` (you will need `import 'dart:io' show Platform;`) along with the content you want to print. Then you can ctrl+click that path in the debug panel to navigate the editor panel to that file.

Comment: I took your advice, but I don't think It's working. I edited the post.